# parsing a XML file in java

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I have wrote a SAX parser. It works fine when the attibute values are nested in double quotes. But if i dont use quote it throws a exception. I want my parser to parse the XML file whose attributes values are not inside quotes.
I want to parse following type of file:

```
<root>
    <tag1 attribute1=value1 > my data  </tag1>
</root>
```

Note that value1 is not inside quotes

Can i make my parser to parse the above file? If yes how?

Answer (score 6):

The SAX parser won't read that because it's not [well-formed XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-well-formed). All attribute values need to be enclosed in either single or double character quotes.

To make your parser read it, you'd find have to tidy/purify/fix it with a relevant library.

Comment: In fact, the XML is not well-formed. Validity refers to validation against a DTD, XSD, or any other kind of syntactical constraints applied to a XML.

Comment: I meant 'additional constraints'... Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try NekoHTML ( http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/usage.html )

e.g.

```
package sample;

import org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser;
import org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration;

public class HTMLSAXParser extends AbstractSAXParser {
    public HTMLSAXParser() {
        super(new HTMLConfiguration());
    }
}
```